# Access variable in C#

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine

I have a problem that I want to solve. I have two classes

```
public class Class1
{
   [ReadOnly] public int Selector
   private void Start()
   {
      Selector = Random.Range(0, 4);
      Debug.Log("Selectorul " + selector);
   }
}

public class Class2
{
   private Class1 sp;
   private void Start()
   {
       Debug.log(sp.Selector);
   }
}
```

I'm a beginner and I want to understand why when I start Unity the second class the selector is always 0?
maybe I do not get right!!!
Help!!!

Comment: this code doesn't compile

Comment: Perhaps `start` has not run in `Class1`?

Comment: why?..............

Comment: `Start()` isnt constructor, it is usual method and it needs to be called. `sp.Start()`

Comment: `I'm a beginner` <= the best advice I can give you is learn to use your debugging tools so you can troubleshoot your own issues which will be many as you are a "beginner". Secondly, follow some tutorials or read some books. Learning to program by trial and error is painful and not recommended.

Comment: this is Unity....Start is the main method

Comment: the code in class 1 works, when you start Selector = a number between 0 and 4

Comment: now I want this number to display in class 2

Comment: as igor mentioned, did you try debugging? set a breakpoint in the Random.Range line in class1, run class2 and inspect what number gets assigned to selector when the execution hits the breakpoint

Comment: @GheorgheCiusca try setting `Random.seed = 5` on start and check if the value is still 0.

Comment: @GheorgheCiusca "this is Unity....Start is the main method" no its not - at least not universally - `Start()` only is a callback for classes deriving from MonoBehaviour.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you are using Unity.

In Unity, the `Start` method of a script is only called if the class derives from `MonoBehaviour`, which yours does not at the moment.

Fix this by simply replacing

```
class Class1
```

with

```
class Class1 : MonoBehaviour
```

Now, if you drag the script onto a GameObject, the `Start` method of `Class1` should get called.

Comment: Or if you dont want to derive from MonoBehaviour, use the constructor instead and create a new instance with the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the seed for the random number generator so every attempt will generate the same number (in your case 0).

Use `Random.initState (int seed)` before  `Selector = Random.Range(0, 4);`

But again this might not even be your problem. Since both `Debug.log()` methods are in Start() how do you make sure which one is ran first?  Also the Classes are not derived from MonoBehaviour so do you call `Start()` yourself? or?

For instance Class2 Start() might run before Class1 sets the value of selector.

Comment: Unity's `Random` class contains static methods and does not have to be initialized.

Comment: Ahh didn't know that |^_^

Comment: @Rostin there is something called execution order which can be either set by script via an attribute, or in the inspector. But you make a good point, OP probably doesnt know about that either.